# WCF InstanceContextMode and serviceThrottling

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In WCF, if I specify the InstanceContextMode to be 'Single' and configure the serviceThrottling in config to be like,

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
```

Will these two settings conflict..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**

*maxConcurrentInstances* and *maxConcurrentSessions* will be ignored since they are not applicable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. can you please provide a link (MSDN or something) which confirms this.. since I have to share this information with my client with some proof.. or do I have to prove it the old fashioned way.. that is write a sample application... :|

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana Direct statement is not there on msdn or at least I haven't seen it but its obvious since these settings are not related to singleton service.